# Creating an array and storing it in sessionStorage with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sessionstorage

I'm doing an assignment that requires us to add objects to a fake cart array from a fake database array, then go to a cart page that displays everything in the "cart." Now, that's all well and good, but for some reason I can't get more than one object to show up in the fakeCart array.

I'm *fairly* certain the issue is in this function, because everything displays properly otherwise in every way.

So, it turns out I posted code that I was tinkering with. I've since updated it to the almost-working one.

```
function addToCart(e) {
'use strict';

var fakeCart = [];

for (var i = 0; i < fakeDatabase.length; i++) {
    if (fakeDatabase[i].id == e.currentTarget.id) {
        fakeCart.push(fakeDatabase[i]);
    }
}

sessionStorage.fakeCart = JSON.stringify(fakeCart);
}
```

Essentially, I can get the code to make a single object go from one array (database) to the other (cart), but whenever I try to add one back in it just replaces the last one.

Comment: what is coming with `fakeDatabase`?

Comment: What is `e, sessionStorage, productNum` variables...can you console.log those and show us in the question?

Comment: I can't see how your posted code sample would work. You're trying to `push` to an undefined element. Did you mean to write `fakeCart.push(fakeDatabase[i]);`?

Answer (score 0):

The code overwrites any existing value of `sessionStorage.fakeCart`, so there will never be more than one element in the serialized array. You can fix that by reading the value from `sessionStorage` instead of creating a new list each time.

```
function addToCart(e, productNum) {
    'use strict';

    // change this
    var fakeCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.fakeCart) || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < fakeDatabase.length; i++) {
        if (fakeDatabase[i].id == e.currentTarget.id) {
            // and this
            fakeCart.push(fakeDatabase[i]);
        }
    }

    sessionStorage.fakeCart = JSON.stringify(fakeCart);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I tried a bunch of different methods to get the fakeCart var to define by the JSON.parse first, but I couldn't get it to work. I can't believe it was that easy.

Edit: Turns out it ALMOST works, but when there's zero items in the cart array (after testing with sessionStorage.clear()) it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

I think :

Instead of

```
fakeCart[i].push(fakeDatabase[i]);
```

you require this

```
fakeCart.splice(i, 0, fakeDatabase[i]);
```